# Another javascript undefined issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having an issue getting this script to run. It's close but it keeps throwing an undefined error anytime I add anything to the button object.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="centerBoxContentsFeatured centeredContent back ie_margin" style="width:33%;"><div class="product-col">
                <div class="tie">
                    <div class="indent2">
                        <div>
                            <a class="name" href="http://localhost:8080/rfs700/index.php?main_page=product_info&amp;cPath=37&amp;products_id=128">TB-0070 Tabletop Interpreter Booth</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="img">
                            <a href="http://localhost:8080/rfs700/index.php?main_page=product_info&amp;cPath=37&amp;products_id=128"><img src="images/products/tb0070.jpg" alt="TB-0070 Tabletop Interpreter Booth" title=" TB-0070 Tabletop Interpreter Booth " width="130" height="130"></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="desc">
                            The TB-0070 Tabletop Interpreter Booth accommodate...
                        </div>
                        <div class="price"><strong><img src="includes/templates/template_default/images/call_for_prices.jpg" alt="Call for Price" title=" Call for Price " width="78" height="20"></strong></div>
                        <div class="buttons">
                            <a href="http://localhost:8080/rfs700/index.php?main_page=products_new&amp;action=buy_now&amp;products_id=128"><img src="includes/templates/theme324/buttons/english/button_in_cart.gif" alt="Add to Cart" title=" Add to Cart " width="106" height="27"></a><a href="http://localhost:8080/rfs700/index.php?main_page=product_info&amp;cPath=37&amp;products_id=128"><img src="includes/templates/theme324/buttons/english/button_goto_prod_details.gif" alt="Go To This Product's Detailed Information" title=" Go To This Product's Detailed Information " width="58" height="27"></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div></div>
```

Here is my javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var doc = $(".centerBoxContentsFeatured .price");
        doc.each(function (){
            var image = $(this).find("img").attr("alt");
            var button = $(this).find(".buttons");
            if (image == "Call for Price"){
                alert(button.find("a:first-child").attr("href"));
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

When I do just alert(button) it displays it as an object. But if I add anything else to the button object for example what is shown in the javascript code above, it displays undefined. Any ideas?

Comment: [object Object] doesn't mean an element was found. In this case, `button.length` is `0` and that completely explains why `button.find("anything").attr("something")` is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(".centerBoxContentsFeatured .price")` does not contain `.buttons`. You need to traverse up one level to get the doc back.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var doc = $(".centerBoxContentsFeatured .price");
        doc.each(function (){
            var image = $(this).find("img").attr("alt");
            var button = $(this).parent().find(".buttons");
            if (image == "Call for Price"){
                alert(button.find("a:first-child").attr("href"));
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Ahhhh. Thank you good sir, I see your point and the issue was resolved. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Glad that was quick ;)

Answer (score 1):

There's a problem while you call `button` event because it is outside of you `$(".centerBoxContentsFeatured .price")`

And  also while you call something like this always make sure that the event you are calling is inside that **element** as of now it is out side of your div and so displaying error.

**Now,** to remove this you need to directly call the button or reference button through exact element in which it lies.

**You solution for this is :**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var doc = $(".centerBoxContentsFeatured .price");
        doc.each(function (){
            var image = $(this).find("img").attr("alt");
            var button = $(this).parent(".tie").find(".buttons");
            if (image == "Call for Price"){
                alert(button.find("a:first-child").attr("href"));
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`var doc = $(".centerBoxContentsFeatured .price");` returns below html element

```
<div class="price">
  <strong>
    <img src="includes/templates/template_default/images/call_for_prices.jpg" alt="Call for Price" title=" Call for Price " width="78" height="20">
  </strong>
</div>
```

here there are no buttons so `$(this).find(".buttons")` yields **empty object**
when you do further `button.find("a:first-child")` operation on button, this will return `null` and hence you will get **exception** when you try to access `attr` of that.

Answer (score 0):

`.buttons` class is not a children of `.centerBoxContentsFeatured .price` is a sibling. Use [`siblings`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) method:

> Description: Get the siblings of each element in the set of matched
>   elements, optionally filtered by a selector.

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var doc = $(".centerBoxContentsFeatured .price");
    doc.each(function () {
        var image = $(this).find("img").attr("alt");
        var button = $(this).siblings(".buttons");
        if (image == "Call for Price") {
            alert(button.find("a:first-child").attr("href"));
        }
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/d5UTW/